# java key pressed event off by one letter

Tags: java, keypress, key-events

this is the method I'm using to test this:

```
     private void searchFieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
        String query = searchField.getText();
        System.out.println(query);
     }
```

if i type one letter though, query contains an empty string
if i type another letter, query contains the single previous letter

so if i type "a", query is empty
If I type "ab", query contains "a"
If i type "abc", query contains "ab"
If I type "abcd", query contains "abc"
and so on.

Comment: Have you tried using a different event, such as KEY_RELEASED?

Comment: Make sure you select an answer so other users don't have to come to this one.

Comment: i tried right away but it said i had to wait 10 minutes or something so i came back when i remembered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, use KEY_RELEASED rather than KEY_PRESSED.